# Not getting any sound or vibration on notification

Tags: android, audio, notifications, vibration

When the notification is received I dont get the sound and the vibration. For information phone is not in mute mode.

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    long[] pattern = {500,500,500};
    builder.setVibrate(pattern);
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    builder.setSound(alarmSound); 
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0,builder.build());
```

Comment: is your phone muted ?

Comment: No it is not muted.

Comment: VIBRATE feature requires <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> permission

Comment: builder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
works too

Comment: Thanks, it worked !